# Security of $(k, 2k)$-bit generator for small seeds

Tags: probability-distributions, cryptography

Here is the problem I am working on for context.

[image: problem 4]

I have $\epsilon \le 1 - 2^{-k}$ and $\epsilon$ approaches 1 as $k \to \infty$ but I'm stuck on part c). The $f$ is secure iff there does not exist a polynomial-time distinguisher but it seems to me that $ran(f)$ would be fairly easy to find for small seeds.

Comment: duplicate of the question below  in crypto.stackexchange, this is generally frowned upon, certainly without cross-referencing. http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/34876/security-of-k-2k-bit-generator-for-small-seeds

Comment: After posting here, I thought that this might not be the most appropriate place for it. Why is it frowned upon, and how would I cross-reference?

Comment: please see discussions on cross-posting on meta math.stackexchange, e.g. http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/21237/is-cross-posting-the-same-question-to-multiple-sites-not-allowed-when-it-is-on-t where it is suggested that if you believe it's on topic on multiple sites, you indicate this by pasting a link to the question on the other site, so that duplicate efforts in answering your question are avoided. you are also able to delete a question you asked, if you decide after the fact it's off topic.